# Setting parent class variable in subclass issue

Tags: php

Why isn't the filename being included in the path when calling the `getLivePath();` and `getDevPath();` methods?

```
<?php

class supplierImport {
    var $_supplierFilename = '';
    var $_fileName = '';
    var $_livePath = '/var/www/vhosts/myshop.co.uk/httpdocs/_import/';
    var $_devPath = '/var/www/web-ecommerce/www/_import/';


    function supplierImport($supplier){
        switch($supplier){
            case 'birlea';
            $birlea = new birlea();
            break;
            case 'julianbowen';
            $julianbowen = new julianbowen();
            default;
            echo 'Supplier not available';
            break;
        }

    }

    function getLivePath(){
        return $this->_livePath.'/'.$this->_fileName;
    }

    function getDevPath(){
        return $this->_devPath.'/'.$this->_fileName;
    }

}


class birlea extends supplierImport {
    function birlea(){
        $this->_fileName = 'birlea_stock.csv';
    }
}

class julianbowen extends supplierImport {
    function julianbowen(){
        $this->_fileName = 'julianbowen_stock.csv';
    }
}

$supplierImport = new supplierImport('birlea');
echo $supplierImport->getLivePath();
echo $supplierImport->getDevPath();
```

This is the output I get:

```
 /var/www/vhosts/myshop.co.uk/httpdocs/_import///var/www/web-ecommerce/www/_import//
```

Example code:

```
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/435a4b25db44d2c8bb33ff6aa2d96c6db21ef177
```

Comment: Looks like you have been reading a very old version of the PHP manual

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I'm having to work with some very old php code

Comment: @user1532669 Which version?

Comment: `$supplierImport = new supplierImport('birlea')` - this still gets you an instance of your `supplierImport` class. The mere fact that inside the constructor you create an instance of `birlea` with `$birlea = new birlea()` doesn’t change anything about that. Yes, `$birlea` now contains a `birlea` instance for which the constructor of that class has been called. But this does not influence what you got stored in `$supplierImport` one single bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extending the base class so you have to instantiate the class that is extending the base class. Then the extended class will run its constructor setting the values correctly.

```
<?php

class supplierImport {
    var $_supplierFilename = '';
    var $_fileName = '';
    var $_livePath = '/var/www/vhosts/myshop.co.uk/httpdocs/_import/';
    var $_devPath = '/var/www/web-ecommerce/www/_import/';

    function getLivePath(){
        return $this->_livePath.$this->_fileName;
        // removed unnecesary `.'/'.`
    }

    function getDevPath(){
        return $this->_devPath.$this->_fileName;
        // removed unnecesary `.'/'.`
    }
}


class birlea extends supplierImport {
    function birlea(){
        $this->_fileName = 'birlea_stock.csv';
    }
}

class julianbowen extends supplierImport {
    function julianbowen(){
        $this->_fileName = 'julianbowen_stock.csv';
    }
}

$birlea = new birlea();
echo 'Birlea Live = ' . $birlea->getLivePath();
echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'Birlea Dev = ' . $birlea->getDevPath();
echo PHP_EOL;
$julian = new julianbowen();
echo 'Julian LIVE = ' . $julian->getLivePath();
echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'Julian DEV = ' . $julian->getDevPath();
```

RESULT

```
Birlea Live = /var/www/vhosts/myshop.co.uk/httpdocs/_import/birlea_stock.csv
Birlea Dev = /var/www/web-ecommerce/www/_import/birlea_stock.csv
Julian LIVE = /var/www/vhosts/myshop.co.uk/httpdocs/_import/julianbowen_stock.csv
Julian DEV = /var/www/web-ecommerce/www/_import/julianbowen_stock.csv
```